# Error response from daemon: No such container: cli (Hyperledger .byfn.sh -m up Error)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to configure hyperledger composer with multi peer. But when I have started the hyperledger fabric, getting following response.

```
amandai@ubuntultop:~/block chain/fabric-samples V1/ess-multipeer-sample      /network$ ./byfn.sh -m up
Starting with channel 'essplchannel' and CLI timeout of '10000' seconand CLI delay of '3' seconds
Continue (y/n)? y
proceeding ...
WARNING: The COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Creating network "network_amsnetwork" with the default driver
Creating orderer.esspl.com ... 
Creating peer0.ezone.esspl.com ... 
Creating peer0.essbbsr.esspl.com ... 
Creating ca_peerEssbbsr ... 
Creating ca_peerezone ... 
Creating peer0.ezone.esspl.com
Creating orderer.esspl.com
Creating ca_peerezone
Creating peer0.ezone.esspl.com ... done
Creating ca_peerEssbbsr ... done
Error response from daemon: No such container: cli
amandai@ubuntultop:~/block chain/fabric-samples V1/ess-multipeer-sample/network$
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.yaml instead of COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose-cli.yaml due to this error came. After modifying it working as expected.

Comment: weren't you using docker-compose-e2e.yml file?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your error may be captured by the **answers** posted here -> [Error when try to instantiate chain-code on Hyperledger Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775044/error-when-try-to-instantiate-chain-code-on-hyperledger-fabric) - perhaps making sure there's no 'space' in your directory name (as shown above) may help /  setting the variable explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error recently and it related to having some conflicting containers already active. In a section of the following it explains how to remove potentially conflicting containers which I followed to remove my occurrence of this issue. https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html

Answer (score 0):

upgrade the docker-compose or reinstall it

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

It solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, docker-composer was missing. Installing it solved the issue.